# Private Key missing? Not able to validate ionic ios app

Tags: ios, ionic3, keychain

Hi Friends we are using ionic V1 from last one year in Mac mini. everything was working fine we were were able to publishing our app in app store. But now in a another MacBook we installed ionic V3 and we are not able to publish our app.

My question is that can we run one developer account simultaneously on two diffrent system? when we validate our app in xcode its saying

**"Account Name" has one ios distribution certificate but its private key is not installed on this syatem**

if we install private key on this Macbook then we are able to publish from another syatem also or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to install the private key used to deploy it from the original server. You may want to consider using a build server instead if you need to deploy from multiple developers. One of many third party options is bitrise.io.